# How to find roots for a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am wondering how to find foots for an array. What I have now is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import brentq as find_root

t = np.linspace(0, 100)

def f(x):
    return x ** 2 - t

a = find_root(f, -400, 400)

print(a)
```

It gives me a type array saying that:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
```

I know the reason is that find_root can only take a scalar in its argument. What I want is to make “a” a bumpy array that finds root for the function given each possible value of t. Does that mean I need to write a loop for find_root? Or do I need to write a loop before I define the function? What’s the easiest way to do it?
Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case it might be easiest to just loop over the arguments.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import brentq as find_root

def f(x, t):
    return x ** 2 - t

a = [find_root(f, 0, 400,args=(i,)) for i in np.linspace(1,10,10)]

print(a)
```

Note that I introduced an argument `t` to your function `f` to which you can pass the value using the `args` parameter of `find_root`.